# Ruta dinámica - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy creando un eccomerce con React y Strapi, necesito crear rutas dinámicas con React Router, este es mi código:

```
/* React components */
import React from 'react';

/* Librarys */
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/productos" />
          <Route exact path="/productos/:product" />
          <Redirect to="/404" />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tengo una ruta (productos), donde muestro todos los productos, a continuación cuando se hace click en la imagen del Producto, te abre una nueva pestaña con la información del producto, me muestra correctamente la url.

**Ejemplo:** Estoy en **`http://localhost:3000/productos`** visualizando los productos del eccomerce, a continuación hago click en un producto llamado 'zapatillas nike', te lleva a la sgte url: **`http://localhost:3000/productos/zapatillas-nike`**.

Aquí todo bien, muestra correctamente la información, pero al navegar en una url que no coincide con el nombre de algún producto, por ejemplo: **`http://localhost:3000/productos/yyyyy`**, sigue mostrando la pantalla pero sin la información del producto, debería mostrarme la ruta 404, no la una página con información vacía del producto, ¿Cómo lograría esto?, traigo los productos de mi api de strapi: **`http://localhost:1337`**.

Comment: No te mostrará la página 404, porque *yyyyy* es un producto(exista o no). Recuerda que tu ruta dice que luego de la ruta *exacta* productos, viene el producto.

Lo que deberías hacer es una condicional, en la que valides si el producto existe o no, en caso que de exista, debes mostrarlo. Si no existe entonces redirigir la página a la página 404 o mejor aún, mostrar un mensaje de no se encuentra el producto.

Comment: Cómo podría hacer dicha validación? Podrías mostrarme un pequeño ejemplo, primera vez que uso react router doom.

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas la información del producto? Una solución es que cuando traigas los datos y estos están vacíos, simplemente redireccionas al usuario al 404 desde tu componente de `Producto`.

Comment: Me estaba complicando la vida con algo tan simple. Creo que la mejor opción es mostrar un mensaje que el producto no se ha encontrado, más no redireccionar a 404. Simplemente lo hice usando: const data = useLocation.state;
  if (!data) {
    return <ProductNotFound />
  } o Redireccionando a 404 con el hook useHistory() =>>>> history.push('/404')

Comment: También se puede intentar `const data = useLocation.state; if (!data) { return <Redirect to="/404"> } `, recuerda que puedes contestar tu propia pregunta, saludos.